# SQL Server Sequence vs Persisted Computed Column? Which one is better for performance?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

If you have to generate a unique serial number such as `T1000`, `T10001`, `T10002` ... and so on.

The two methods that come to mind are:

1. Persisted computed column
2. User-defined sequence

Is there is a performance advantage of using one over the other?

Comment: can you please tell how do you plan to generate persisted computed column ?

Comment: Without knowing how you use it, how the rows change over time, if the column value is every modified? Nothing is free and there are no generic performance answer. You try both and evaluate performance based on execution plans - not by guessing.

Comment: @VenkataramanR something like : ALTER TABLE dbo.Products ADD SerialNo AS ('T'+ID) PERSISTED

Comment: @SMor assume SerialNo is going to be unique. Concatenation of alphabet'T' + Identity Column value. 

It is not going to change. This serialno is likely to appear in where clause often.

Comment: [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: @ZoharPeled I totally disagree with your opinion. There is a large community who has used both. Who understand the internals of it better than I do. Why shouldn't I ask them before implementing something and finding out that it was a bad choice 3 months later when there is no going back?

Comment: @SamuraiJack You totally misunderstood what I meant by giving you the link. There should be no reason why you shouldn't do a small-scale (or even a large-scale) test yourself. It shouldn't take 3 months also - this is something that can be simulated and tested in well under 3 hours - I would even dare to say under one hour. SQL Performance tuning requires an intimate knowledge of the requirements as well as of the technical specs of the SQL Server and in some cases, the machine it's running on. All this knowledge is something you should have but we can only guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did a comparison of performance for IDENTITY Vs SEQUENCE. I find that IDENTITY is little better performance, as it is having lesser IO & lesser CPU.

**Performance Test setup**

```
CREATE TABLE #test_Identity
(
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
NAME CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
TID AS CONCAT('T',ID) PERSISTED)

CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.SEQ_VAL Start with 1 increment by 1;

CREATE TABLE #test_seq
(
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
NAME CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'A',
TID CHAR(10) NOT NULL)

SET STATISTICS IO ON
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
```

**Performance Test: Inserting 10000 rows.**

- **Using Sequence**

```
    INSERT INTO #test_seq(TID)
    SELECT CONCAT('T',NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.SEQ_VAL)
    FROM (SELECT TOP 10000 * FROM sys.objects) AS T

SQL Server parse and compile time:     CPU time = 14 ms, elapsed time
    = 14 ms. 
Table '#test_seq_____00000000569F'. Scan count 0, logical reads 21418, physical reads 0, 
read-ahead reads 30,lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. 

Table 'sysschobjs'. Scan count 1, logical reads 242, physical reads 0, 
read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 141 ms,  elapsed time = 247 ms.
```

- **Using Identity**

```
    INSERT INTO #test_Identity(Name)
    SELECT top 10000 'A'
    FROM sys.objects

SQL Server parse and compile time:     CPU time = 13 ms, elapsed time
    = 13 ms. 
Table '#test_______________00000000569D'. Scan count 0, logical reads 21413, physical reads 0, 
read-ahead reads 31, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, 
lob read-ahead reads 0. Table 'sysschobjs'. Scan count 1, logical reads 242, physical reads 0,
read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 110 ms,  elapsed time = 101 ms.
```

Comment: `CPU time = 141 ms,  elapsed time = 247 ms`. vs `CPU time = 110 ms,  elapsed time = 101 ms.` Not a huge difference but its good to know. 
BTW do you think higher IOs could have any role in causing deadlocks?

Comment: Yes. IOs are very important factor in the performance tuning. If IO is more, it can lead to taking more time to get data and in turn the lock getting longer. and can cause blocking scenarios and deadlock. Refer to this article on importance of IO with respect to performance tuning: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/simple-query-tuning-with-statistics-io-and-execution-plans/